# Next JS router not changing page in async function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am very new to promises and JS in general, but I am working on creating a register page using a tutorial on YouTube. I am currently using next.js with react and TypeScript to redirect to the user to the home page if no errors occur when registering (no email, password too short, etc.), but the router won't redirect the user within an async onSubmit function.

Here is the current non-working code. The useRegisterMutation hook just creates a function that takes in the input fields and creates a user in the db for me:

```
const Register: React.FC<registerProps> = ({}) => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [register] = useRegisterMutation();
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <Formik initialValues={{first_name: "", last_name: "", email: "", password: ""}}
                    onSubmit={async (values, {setErrors}) => {
                        const response = await register({
                            variables: {
                                email: values.email,
                                pass: values.password,
                                fname: values.first_name,
                                lname: values.last_name
                            }
                        });

                        // A user is returned, meaning there were no errors
                        if (response.data?.createUser?.user) {
                            await router.push("/");

                        // An error was returned, meaning that the user was not created
                        } else if (response.data?.createUser?.errors) {
                            setErrors(setErrorMap(response.data.createUser.errors));
                        }
                    }}>

//        -----------     Unimportant HTML     -----------

            </Formik>
         </Wrapper>
    );
}

export default Register;
```

When I remove async / await from the onSubmit function, the router begins correctly working, but the if statements do not work correctly because they are expecting response to be a promise, so they fail every time. Is there some trick to get the router to push to the correct url while still keeping the function as a promise?

Answer (score -1):

Your async code seems to be fine, and you're saying the redirect works without async.

It seems that you might not be getting what you're expecting to get.
I'd log the `response` and `response.data` and all of the subsequent properties that you need for your if statement.

p.s.
Feel free to share the tutorial, you might've missed something or maybe it has a mistake.